# Collapsing the Exponential time Hierarchy with a complete language as oracle

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory

It is known that $\mathsf{P^A=NP^A}$ is true for every $\mathsf{EXP}$ complete language $\mathsf{A}$. The question is the whether the similar things hold for Exponential time Hierarchy.

> Is there any complexity class $\mathcal{C}$ and a $\mathcal{C}$ complete problem $\mathsf{B}$ such that $\mathsf{EXP^B=NEXP^B}$ but$\mathsf{P^B\not =NP^B}$?

Comment: Wouldn't a padding argument show that this works for any $\sf B$ with $\sf P^B=NP^B$?

Comment: @Wojowu: I forgot to write the $P^B\not =NP^B$ condition.